# Prop types not matching when passing props to react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mantine

In the code below I get the following error on every component, let's take `<TextInput` for example:

```
Type '{ onChange?(value: number | ""): void; value?: number | "" | undefined; defaultValue?: number | "" | undefined; decimalSeparator?: string | undefined; thousandsSeparator?: string | undefined; ... 370 more ...; type: ValidatedInputTypes; } | ... 6 more ... | { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TextInputProps & RefAttributes<HTMLInputElement>'.
  Type '{ onChange?(value: number | ""): void; value?: number | "" | undefined; defaultValue?: number | "" | undefined; decimalSeparator?: string | undefined; thousandsSeparator?: string | undefined; ... 370 more ...; type: ValidatedInputTypes; }' is not assignable to type 'TextInputProps'.
    Types of property 'onChange' are incompatible.
      Type '((value: number | "") => void) | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> | undefined'.ts(2322)
```

This is the code:

```
import { ..., TextInput, TextInputProps } from '@mantine/core';
import ...

export type ValidatedInputTypes = 'accent' | 'country' | 'date' | 'email' | 'number' | 'password' | 'tel' | 'text' | 'url' | 'multi' | 'file';

export type ValidatedInputProps<T = ValidatedInputTypes> = { type: T } & (T extends 'accent'
  ? AccentColorSelectProps
  (...)
  : T extends 'number'
  ? NumberInputProps
  : TextInputProps);

export default function ValidatedInput({ type = 'text', ...otherProps }: ValidatedInputProps) {
  const props = { type, ...otherProps };
  const { classes } = useStyles();

  switch (type) {
    case 'accent':
      return (
        ...
      );
    case 'password':
      return (
        <PasswordInput
          classNames={classes}
          {...props}
        />
      );
    default:
      return (
        <TextInput
          classNames={classes}
          {...props}
        />
      );
  }
}
```

Like this it'd work:

```
    default:
      return (
        <TextInput
          classNames={classes}
          {...(props as TextInputProps)}
        />
      );
```

Why does my typing not work? How can I resolve this issue?